# CloudFormation validate environment variable against regex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to validate an environment variable against a regex pattern in a CloudFormation template?

Something like this, but `AllowedPattern` can't actually be used like this.

```yaml
Conditions:
  IsValidVersion: !AllowedPattern [!Sub ${APP_VERSION}, "rel-\\d{4,8}" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFormation templates are executed on the AWS service side, they have no access to any environment variables. What you can do is to specify parameter and assign allowed pattern to it:

```yaml
Parameters: 
    AppVersion:
        Type: "String"
        AllowedPattern: "rel-\\d{4,8}"
```

And execute CLI command passing environment variable:

```bash
aws cloudformation deploy \
    --stack-name your-stack \
    --template-file your-template \
    --parameter-overrides AppVersion=${APP_VERSION}
```